# How can I flush HTTP Headers from Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, .net-core, export-to-csv

I want to stream a .csv export file to the client. I need to send HTTP headers to the client so the client shows the downloading file. Then I want to start streaming the .csv file to the client.

The code below doesn't work for me. The method `Response.Body.Flush()` repeats the whole `ExecuteExport()` method.

```
public FileStreamResult ExecuteExport()
{
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "someType");
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "export.csv");

    // Trying to flush Http Headers
    Response.Body.Flush();

    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    // Start exporting and streaming .csv file to client
    this.ExportAndStream(ref outputStream);

    return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, type)
    {
        FileDownloadName = "export.csv"
    };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to clear the `Headers`, you shouldn't flush the `Body`... For one, flushing makes sure all currently buffered output is sent to the client. And second, body != headers.

You can use the [HttpResponse.ClearHeaders Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.clearheaders?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Web_HttpResponse_ClearHeaders)

> Clears all headers from the buffer stream.

Be sure to clear the headers *before* you add yours:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "someType");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "export.csv");
```

Comment: "flushing makes sure all currently buffered output is sent to the client" - that is exactly what I am looking for. I don't know how to do that.